# Visual Basic SplashScreen not working with Version Select Form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'll try and keep  this brief without leaving out details. I'm working in Visual Stuido 2012 using .NET 4.5

I have a Splash Screen, a "version selection" form as my main startup form, and then from there it branches out in two ways based on the user's choice.

The Version Select can save the user's choice for the future, and checks if they have a saved setting, and if they do it skips the selection form and goes straight to their version. The problem I'm encountering is that when the user has a saved version, the splash screen remains up and never closes unless I force it to.

I tried using the MinimumSplashScreen time in the application events but that hasn't helped. This only happens if the user has a version saved.

Any thoughts on this? I can post more details as needed. Thanks in advance

---

From Comments

```
Private Sub Version_Selection_Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
    If My.Settings.VersionSelected = "OSRS" Then 
        'Code to close initial form and load old school 
        Dim OSmain As New OldSchoolMain 
        OSmain.Show() 
        Me.Close() 
    ElseIf My.Settings.VersionSelected = "RS3" Then 
        'Code to close intital form and load RS3 
    End If 
End Sub

Private Sub btnConfirmSelection_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConfirmSelection.Click 
    If radOSRS.Checked = True Then 
        If cboxSaveVersion.Checked = True Then 
            My.Settings.VersionSelected = "OSRS" 
        End If 
        Dim OSmain As New OldSchoolMain 
        OSmain.Show() 
        Me.Close() 
    ElseIf radRS3.Checked = True Then 
        If cboxSaveVersion.Checked = True Then 
            My.Settings.VersionSelected = "RS3" 
        End If 
        Dim RS3main As New RS3Main 
        RS3main.Show() 
        Me.Close() 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you creating/showing your splash screen, then how are you showing your different forms.

Comment: I'm using the project properties to add the splash screen. The versions select is the main start-up form, and once a user makes a selection OR it reads the setting they saved, it creates a new instance of the form relating to their choice and shows it. If the version select screen comes up, it creates the new instance, shows it, and then closes itself.

Comment: @MarkHall
Is not using the application framework going to require major any major recoding or cause issues as I continue building? 

And my code is setup a bit differently, It uses 2 radio buttons and a checkbox for the option to save. 

  If radio1.Checked = True Then
                If cboxSaveVersion.Checked = True Then
                    My.Settings.VersionSelected = "value1"
                End If
                
                Dim formV1 As New Form
                formV1.Show()
                Me.Close()
ElseIF 
(code for 2nd option is similar)
end if

Is using a module the best way?

Comment: That is why I removed my answer, it would have removed the easy splash screen and required you to create and implement one from scratch. I have done this in the past. If you post the code that you are using to show your screens I may be able to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Private Sub Version_Selection_Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        If My.Settings.VersionSelected = "OSRS" Then
            'Code to close initial form and load old school 
            Dim OSmain As New OldSchoolMain
            OSmain.Show()
            Me.Close()

        ElseIf My.Settings.VersionSelected = "RS3" Then
            'Code to close intital form and load RS3
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: 'Private Sub btnConfirmSelection_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConfirmSelection.Click
  If radOSRS.Checked = True Then
    If cboxSaveVersion.Checked = True Then
       My.Settings.VersionSelected = "OSRS"
          End If
       Dim OSmain As New OldSchoolMain
       OSmain.Show()
       Me.Close()

    ElseIf radRS3.Checked = True Then
      If cboxSaveVersion.Checked = True Then
        My.Settings.VersionSelected = "RS3"
      End If
        Dim RS3main As New RS3Main
        RS3main.Show()
        Me.Close()
       End If
    End Sub
End Class'

Comment: I apologize that it's so messy. I couldn't find anything about formatting code blocks :x

Comment: You can't in the comments should be added to your answer I am doing that right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, I think the problem with your Splash Screen is that you are closing the startup form before it finishes. I would try using the Form [`Shown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event since that doesn't get fired until the SplashScreen has finished, I also am Minimizing the form to try to keep it from flashing briefly on the screen. See if something like this works for you.

```
Private Sub Splash_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    If My.Settings.StartupForm = "Form1" Then
        Dim frm As New Form1
        frm.Show()
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
        Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
        Me.Close()
   ElseIf My.Settings.StartupForm = "Form2" Then
        Dim frm As New Form2
        frm.Show()
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
        Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```